# Socket.IO - How to Identify User is Admin UI?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, firebase-admin

## Because of verification Admin UI is not working and i want to Skip Verification for admin Ui User

I want to use Socket.IO [admin ui](https://socket.io/docs/v4/admin-ui/) in my previous Node.JS app but i am verifing token for each user from middleware if the user is verified i'm calling next() .
So i wanna know if user is socket io so that i can skip token verification and let them go.
Here is my minimized code for verifying user

```
io.use(function (client, next) {
const idToken = client.handshake.query['idtoken'];
const uidGot = client.handshake.query['uidPersonal'];
if (idToken != null && uidGot != null) {
    admin
        .auth()
        .verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            const validUser = uidGot === decodedToken.uid
            if (validUser) {
                next(); // this line is important porque this is saying to go next
            } else {
                next(new Error("Invalid user"))
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            next(new Error("Invalid user"))
        });

} else {
    next(new Error('Invalid User'));
}
```

Comment: I got the solution => [link](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-admin-ui/issues/20)